# What will be the best choice for batch size for one device (using Mirrored Strategy in TF)?

Tags: tensorflow, batchsize

**Question:**
Suppose you have 4 GPUs (having 2GB memory each) to train your deep learning model. You have 1000 data points in your dataset that takes around 10 GB of storage. What will be the best choice for batch size for one device (using Mirrored Strategy in TF)?

Can someone help me to solve this assignment problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My another question in continuation is:
In the previous case what is the overall batch size being used?

Answer (score 1):

Each GPU has a memory of 2GB and there are 4 GPUs which means you have a total of 8 GB memory to work with. 
Now you can't divide 10 GB of data into 8 GB in one go, so you split 10GB into halves, and have an overall batch size of 500 data points(or rather 512 to be closer to a power of 2)

Now you distribute these 500 data points across the 4 GPUs, getting a batch size of ~128 data points per device.

So overall batch size would be 512 data points, and per GPU batch size would 128.